# Assigning values to a list, identity

Tags: python, list

Simple question, but this is giving me trouble.

I have a list with lists inside, can be a function with two variables, say x,y and the result, z, so the list is built like

```
a = [ [[x1,y1,z11], [x1,y2,z12], ...],
      [[x2,y1,z21], [x2,y2,z22], ...],
      ... ]
```

Now, I want to build another of this objects, with a different function, let say w:

```
b = [ [[x1,y1,w11], [x1,y2,w12], ...],
      [[x2,y1,w21], [x2,y2,w22], ...],
      ... ]
```

Then, to do it, I do this:

```
b = [[0.0]*len(a[0])]*len(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        c = a[i][j][:2]
        c.append(w(i,j))
        b[i][j] = c
```

ok. Now, when I ask for `a[i][j]`, I get `b[i][j]`. This is puzzling me because when I try this in the terminal I get the correct `a[i][j]`. Any help?

Comment: You didn't show us the code you are actually using.  `for i in len(a):` won't ever run.  Show us real code exhibiting the behaviour you ask about, otherwise we can't find your bug

Comment: Is it really necessary to have triple-nested lists? I'm trying to replicate your error right now.

Comment: Also, there's no need to initialize the list b like you do in `b = [[0.0] * len(a[0])] * len(a)` just use `b.append()`

Comment: in fact, there's a 'range' missing, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 b = [[0.0]*len(a[0])]*len(a)
 # or in two steps
 x = [0.0] * len(a[0]) # one list
 b = [x] * len(a)      # lots of references to that same list
```

What you need to make are new lists:

```
# makes a new inner list for every m
b = [[0.0]*len(a[0]) for m in xrange(len(a))]
```

Comment: What you suggest actually solve the problem, the thing is that I was re-using a code that is what i posted but it works fine. Anyway, this is ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `c = a[i][j][:2]` gives you a reference to the actual list in `a`. When you append something to it, you're modifying `a`. Instead, just write

```
c = a[i][j][:2] + [ w(i, j) ]
```

Now `c` is a different list and you can safely save it in `b`